# Parsing using in swift using Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alamofire

I am trying to parse this api response but I am getting this error

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x1e06425d8) to
>   'NSData' (0x1e06418e0)"

. Here is my code, api response and model class.

```
class func getCityApi(viewController: UIViewController,
                      completion:@escaping (_ result:[CityDetails])->(),
                      errorHandler:@escaping (_ result:Error,_ statusCode:Int?)->()
) {

    AF.request(KCity, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result{
        case.success(let data):
            do{
                let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: data as! Data)
                print(jsonData)
                completion(jsonData.data)
            }
            catch{

            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Api Response structrue

[image]

Model Class

```
struct City: Codable {
  var data: [CityDetails]
  var status: Bool
  var message: String
}

struct CityDetails: Codable{
  var id: Int
  var location: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Data` response. Replace

```
AF.request(KCity, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
```

with

```
AF.request(KCity, method: .get, parameters: nil, headers: nil).responseData { response in
```

and

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: data as! Data)
```

with

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: data)
```

Comment: Sir after replacing it is going in catch block.

Comment: Then it's a `Decoding` problem. In the `catch` block print the `error` instance (**not** its `localizedDescription`)

Comment: Correct its decoding issue. Thanks sir.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: data as! Data)
```

change it to

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(City.self, from: data as! Dictionary<String,Any>)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `Decodable` type, you can just use `responseDecodable` directly, no need to parse the response yourself:

```swift
AF.request(KCity).responseDecodable(of: City.self) { response in
    // response is DataResponse<City, AFError>
}
```

You can find out more by reading Alamofire's [Usage documentation](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md).